# Find overlap in array of start and end dates

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have an array with arrays of date ranges (year only) as such:

```
$dates = array(array('sy'=>2015, 'ey'=>2017),
               array('sy'=>2010, 'ey'=>2012),
               array('sy'=>2011, 'ey'=>2016)     
);
```

How can I find a common date range resulting in one start year and one end year from the provided dates? If multiple date ranges are present, I'm looking for the most current date range.

I'm looking for this to output an array with the common start year and end year as such:

```
$dateRangeResult = array('sy'=>$commonStartYear, 'ey'=>$commonEndYear);
```

Comment: show how should look the expected result

Comment: I edited the question to show the desired format of the result

Comment: Question still isn't clear IMO. If I have ranges 2013-2019 and 2011-2018 what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I may have this figured out.

In essence, I've taken each year span, and filled the years in from start to end years, added them to an array and removed any unique values. This takes care of overlapping years and identifies possible gaps in year ranges.

```
$years = array();
foreach($dates as $yearSet){                                        
    for($i = $yearSet['sy']; $i<= $yearSet['ey']; $i++){
        array_push($years, $i);
    }
}
$years = array_unique($years);
```

Then I created a range from the first date to the last date to figure out where (if there are) gaps are in the year ranges.

```
$firstYr = min($years);
$lastYr = max($years);
$compare = range($firstYr, $lastYr, 1);
$missYrs = array_diff($compare, $years);
```

If there are gaps in the year range, $missYr will contain an array of those years. If not, the $firstYr and $lastYr represent a whole range and can be returned as is. If there is a gap or gaps I want to get the last one, and retrieve the latest year range.

```
if ($missYrs){
    $lastBreak = max($missYrs);
    //in order to find the start year of the highest year range, add a year to the highest break date. Naturally, the end date would then be the $lastYear.  
    $k = array_search(($lastBreak + 1), $years);
    $dateRangeResult['sy'] = $years[$k];
    $dateRangeResult['ey'] = $lastYr;

}else{
    $dateRangeResult['sy'] = $firstYr;
    $dateRangeResult['ey'] = $lastYr;
}
```